# Exception in executing publishing in VS2013

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a asp.net web forms template with individual accounts without any modifications. When I try to publish this application to my web server I'm receiving the following error:

> Exception in executing Publishing: Cannot load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.Contracts, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture neutral, PublishKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Has anyone else ever received this error? I'm getting the error message after I right click on my project and select 'publish'. I've done some googling but haven't found any solutions.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the version of VS I'm using is Visual Studio Professional 2013 and my webforms project is .NET 4.5

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) by following these steps:

1. Go to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads and on click the
   “VS 2013 Install” link under .NET category
2. Download and install the Windows Azure SDK installer which uses
   Microsoft’s WPI (Web Platform Installer)

http://digital.voyage/2014/03/28/exception-in-executing-publishing-error-in-vs2013/